# :button selector not working in firefox and ie

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors, onbeforeunload, unbind

Kindly help me
:button selector to unbind the events from all the buttons in my Spring MVC project is working fine in chrome but not in firefox and internet explorer.

My task is to unbind the event from all the buttons in the project .  The code is as follows :

```js
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
  
j$(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery(window).bind(
      "beforeunload",
      function() {
        return confirm("do you want to exit?" , "true");
      }
  );
  
   jQuery(":button").on('click', function(){
            jQuery(window).unbind('beforeunload')
         });
   
  jQuery('a').on('click', function(){
        jQuery(window).unbind('beforeunload')
    }); 
 
  
jQuery(window).bind('keydown keyup', function(e) {
    if(e.which === 116) {
       jQuery(window).unbind('beforeunload');
    }
    if(e.which === 82 && e.ctrlKey) {
       jQuery(window).unbind('beforeunload');
    }
});


jQuery(window).mousedown(function(e){ 
    if( e.button == 2 ) { 
      jQuery(window).unbind('beforeunload');
    } 
     else{
     jQuery(window).bind('beforeunload');
     }
  }); 

  
jQuery("form").submit(function(){
   jQuery(window).unbind('beforeunload')
    }); 
 
 
 });
```

Now this is working fine in chrome but not in ie and firefox. Please help me to correct this code or suggest me some other way to unbind the event from all buttons . 
Many Thanks in advance

Hi I just got the actual problem . The problem is because of the type of the input element that is button , which is creating problem. If we set the input type of the button to "submit" it works fine in Firefox and others. But if the input type of the button is set to "button" , then it does not work. I mean this  to  . Kindly help me. How to fix this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you upload your html-code too?

Comment: You can find and download the code at :

http://bit.ly/1VBEzjD   

and you can test this at :

 http://goo.gl/CcYlAh

In chrome , it is executing the code 

jQuery(":button").on('click', function(){
            jQuery(window).unbind('beforeunload')
         });

and it is not giving alert on button click. But in firefox , it is giving the alert and then it is executing this above code to unbind the beforeunload event.

Comment: I just got the actual problem . The problem is because of the type of the input element ie . button , which is creating problem. If we set the input type of the button to "submit" it works fine in Firefox and others. But if the input type of the button is set to "button" , then it does not work. I mean this <input type="button" class="Button" name="but" /> to <input type="submit" class="Button" name="but" /> . Kindly help me. How to fix this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

oh, now I see what you mean.
The Problem was, that you have been assigned the *disableButton*-function to the button (within of HTML)... and THEN with Java Script (after the document were ready) assigned another function [*jQuery(":button").on('click', ...)... unbind()* ]

The problem lies in the call-order: 
First *disableButton* and than *unbind()*. And the desired behavior is achievable only with reverse order.

My proposition were either to use submit (like you said before, with almost no js) or to add **j$(this).unbind("beforeunload");** to *disableButton()* (it works in firefox and ie too :-) ):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="demo-Dateien/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function disableButton() {
                j$(this).unbind("beforeunload");
                document.form.method="GET";
                document.form.but.disabled = true;
                document.form.submit();
            }

            var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

            j$(document).ready(function() {
                  j$(window).bind(
                        "beforeunload",
                        function() {
                          return confirm("do you want to exit?" , "true");
                        }
                    );
             });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="form" action="process.jsp" method="post">
            <label>First Name</label>
            <input name="fname" type="text">
            <br>
            <label>Last Name</label>
            <input name="lname" type="text">
            <br>
            <input class="Button" name="but" value="Next" onclick="javascript:disableButton()" type="button">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sir for your help ,  but in our project every other jsp page has a button like this and a disableButton() function attached to it . So by your answer , I will have to change each and every jsp page of the project. This is quite a tough task. Is there any other way out possible ? And Sir, one more query,  It is working fine in chrome , then why it is not working fine in ie and firefox ?

Comment: Hi, [*in practice, browser implementations differ from the standards and from each other... In some cases, two browsers may both implement a feature but with different behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Compatibility_considerations). So maybe chrome doesn't interpret ***js.submit()*** as leaving the site.

If you use the same function on several pages, you may outsource it to a separate .js-file, and than just include it (like you did with jquery). [Copy-pasted code smells :-)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell)

Answer (score 1):

its working in firefox..............

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
    <html>
      <head>
      <title></title>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

     <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("button").click(function(){
        alert("Hello");
      });
    });
    </script>

      </head>
      <body>
       <button> hello</button>
      </body>
    </html>
```